# GET request to find those keys as array where age's value is equal to 30 from the API below https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I can not find any solutions. Please help me.

My expectation is:

> ["IAfpK","WNVdi","JukI","hjgut","gjhg"]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to send the data from API in below JSON format

```
var dt=[{ 'key':'IAfpK', 'age':58 }, 
        {  'key':'WNVdi', 'age':30 }]
```

Then Apply Filter and return key where age is 30

```
dt.filter(x=>x.age==30).map(x=> {return x.key})
```

Or if you don't want to change API which I suggest to change try below.

```
var data={"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68}

var model = data.data.split(',')

var result = d.data.split(',').map((x,i)=>{if(x.trim()=='age=30'){return [i-1];}}).filter(x=>x!=undefined).map(x=>{return model[x].split('=')[1]})
```